# Bootstrap tooltip background not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a tooltip on bootstrap. I want to use the tooltip for a `<td>` text. But my tooltip is just displaying without any background style. It just showing as simple general tooltip.

See my code:

```
<td><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Test title">Test</a></td>
```

NOTE: It's an HTML page. And this page has the following list of scripts:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.validation/jquery.validation.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.stellar/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.gmap/jquery.gmap.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/isotope/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

And CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-elements.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-blog.css">
```

Comment: Have you added the javascript, too?

Comment: nope, maybe I am missing something script. please tell me the js code. Where should I add?

Comment: Depends on what you're using for your site? Simple HTML/PHP?

Comment: I did not change anything on my bootstrap folder. Another bootstrap things are working fine instead of tooltip. I m on wordpress. Not sure which js file I am missing or which code?

Comment: It's an HTMl page and this page has following scripts supports.

Comment: Coud you please put this into your main post and mark it as code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Opt-in functionality
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them
>   by their data-toggle attribute: Copy
>
> ```
> $(function () {   
>   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() 
> })
> ```
>
> (Source: [Bootstrap-Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips))

So you can add this to your html file just before your closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {   
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() 
    })
</script>
```

Or you simply created a JS file (for example application.js) with this code:

```
$(function () {   
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() 
})
```

And load it up in your html head like this:

```
<script src="application.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

Okay so you should definitly go with the second approach I posted. Here's what you are going to do:

Create a file called `application.js`, put it into your `vendor`-folder and fill it with following code:

```
$(function () {   
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() 
})
```

After that add this code to your head (where you load all your javascripts) but make sure you put it somewhere under the line where you load the `bootstrap.js`:

```
<script src="vendor/application.js"></script>
```

Then it should work.

Comment: That's not really helpful. Could you copy the <head> of your html file into your main post please?

Comment: I already accepted your answer. But for marking as helpful I need 15 rep. Currently my rep is under 15. Thanks again for your time. Also thank to others who tried to provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Tooltips must be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element
>   and call the tooltip() method.

To initialize all tooltips you can simply write this code. Of course you need to include in your project bootstrap.js file.

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
       title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
       class="red-tooltip">Tooltip on bottom</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").tooltip();
});
</script>
<style>
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
</style>
```

Comment: plese add similar to this to ur code using class some css i think it will work